# Transformer Design Calculation

Tags: transformer, ac, design

[image]
[image]
What does "For secondary 4 wires of 24SWG in parallel" means?
Does it mean I take 4 wires and wound them 47 times in the primary side?

Comment: Yes, there should be colons after ‘primary’ and ‘secondary’.

Answer (score 3):

It means take 4 24SWG wire and then make them parrelel connection and then do 47 turns.

The wire should be made of 4 strand first, then only it should be wound.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use 4 wires in one strand and then wind the bobbin.

Comment: use insulation tape to isolate primary and secondry winding.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it means take 4 strands of 24 SWG, connect them in parallel (or fold as Kevin suggested) and wind the bunch around the bobbin/core to make up the secondary.

The parallel strands vs. a single strand reduce the AC resistance (due to skin effect) and therefore the losses.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - determine the total length of wire you will need (plus some extra) then fold it back on itself four times for the secondary to create a bunch of 4 wires in parallel then wind that round the bobbin/core 47 times.

For the primary fold it onto itself to create a bunch pf 32 wires and wind 6 turns.

Using multiple wires rather than one thick wire gives lower losses and can give a better packing factor than a single thick wire.

Make sure you solder to all the strands when making the end terminations.